# Function to create a table and insert a value in it

Tags: lua

I have a table clock I want to use to store times when some things are set to happen. Multiple things can happen at the same time and I don't have a hard limit on how far into the future these are to be set.

Let's say I want action a1 happen at time 5. Using...

```
clock = {}
table.insert(clock[5], a1)
```

...won't work, as clock[5] isn't defined and returns nil. So I created a function to check if the table exists and declare it before inserting the value:

```
function insertNil(tab, val)
    if tab == nil then tab = {} end
    table.insert(tab, val)
return 
end
```

Calling `insertNil(clock[5], a1)` doesn't work either, as the `tab` table in the function points to a different (if identical) table from the one I need to modify and I can't figure out how to work directly with my table `clock[5]` within the function.

In the end I came up with this:

```
function insertNil(tab, val)
    if tab == nil then tab = {} end
    table.insert(tab, val)
return tab
end

clock[5] = insertNil(clock[5], a1)
```

That works the way I want it to, but it feels kinda cumbersome and I can't shake the feeling there's an easier solution.

Comment: It seems that you want simply `clock[5]=a1`.

Comment: Well, yeah, that would work, but I need to store multiple values there and at different times. So `clock[5]={a1, a2}` would work, but I couldn't do it separately. The tables `clock[index]` are supposed to be able to store any number of values, or nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way is to write a function that takes 3 arguments. You must pass `clock` to the function, because the function sometimes needs to modify it.

```
local function addAction(clock, index, val)
    -- If the table isn't already there, add it.
    clock[index] = clock[index] or {}
    -- Insert the value.
    table.insert(clock[index], val)
end

clock = {}
addAction(clock, 5, a1)
```

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks! I didn't realize I had to pass the table and the index separately. Makes sense, since what I was passing wasn't a table yet, just an empty identifier. And thanks for reminding me to use `clock[index] = clock[index] or {}`. I keep forgetting that's an option. Cheers!